# sed replace with unknown section in css

Tags: sed

I could use an assist with a sed search and replace.

In this situation the file is css and the section I want to replace is among other values being set in the css.  The following works:

```
sed -i 's/PlayButton-playCircle-kffp_v{border:2px solid hsla(0,0%,100%,.7);border-radius:50%;color:hsla(0,0%,100%,.7);display:inline-block/PlayButton-playCircle-kffp_v{border:2px solid hsla(0,0%,100%,.7);border-radius:50%;color:hsla(0,0%,100%,.7);display:none/g' file.css
```

But in another file.css where I wish to do the same thing the values surrounding the 'display:inline-block' may be in a different order.  So it would make more sense to use something like a '.*' like "PlayButton-playCircle-kffp_v{.*;display:inline-block".

The css file is being generated automatically, once generated it is fixed, but I can't be sure what order the attributes are within the {}, I need to match the item with PlayButton-playCircle-...... that has the attribute display:inline-block and change to display:none.

---

Updating with answer formed with information from both commenters:

sed -i 's/\(PlayButton-playCircle-......{[^}]*;\)display:inline-block/\1display:none/g' $maincss

Instead of .*, [^}]* is used to match in the same way as .* but not matching '}' if found.  This ensures the match is kept to one level of depth within {}.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

You can rewrite it a bit as follows.

```
sed -i 's/\(PlayButton-playCircle-kffp_v{.*\)display:inline-block/\1display:none/g' file.css
```

The text between `\(` and `\)` will be captured and can be referenced as `\1` in the replacement string.

Comment: `/a.*b/` matches `a-b` but also `a-b-b-b-b-b` so this can change the wrong `display` (very likely if this is minimised css with everything on one line)

Comment: @jhnc what about using [^}]* rather than .*?  to only match between one level of {}

Comment: @karezza Yes, that would probably be more reliable, as long as this is plain css (not sass, etc) and you don't have any [nested blocks](https://www.w3.org/TR/css-nesting-1/) before the display property. `[^}]` should also protect against the situation where you have any `PlayButton-playCircle-kffp_v` that do not contain a `display`.